# Intersect and Sum lists with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have this list of id's:

```
string[] ids = { "AF1", "AF2", "AF3" };
```

and my goal is to intersect the ids of this list with the table below and sum the age in a single linq query without making a foreach:

```
   PersonId  |Name        |Age
    AF1      |John        |20
    AF2      |Oscar       |50        
    AF3      |Peter       |30        
    AF4      |Abbey       |65        
    AF5      |Adrian      |43        
    AF6      |Barbara     |15
```

i found that by doing:

```
order.Lines.Select(x => x.PersonId).Intersect(ids);
```

i get all the id's in the table but didnt found a way to sum the age :/
the output must be `100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `.Select()` you are throwing away all info except the IDs, so the Age becomes unreachable. A better approach is by using `.Where()` and `.Contains()`, and then you can sum the Age fields that are returned from that:

```
var sumOfAges = order.Lines.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.PersonId)).Sum(x => x.Age);
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution can be likes the following:

```
var sum = order.Lines.Where(x => ids.Any(x.PersonId)).Sum(x=> x.Age);
```

Comment: No need to first convert to list.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you wanted but if anyone else comes across this

Sum per id:

```
var ids = new string[] {"AF1", "AF2", "AF3"};
var persons = new Person[]
{
    new Person("AF1", "John", 20),
    new Person("AF1", "Oscar", 50),
    new Person("AF2", "Peter", 30),
    new Person("AF2", "Abbey", 65),
    new Person("AF3", "Adrian", 43),
    new Person("AF3", "Barbara", 15)
};
var groups = persons.Where(p => ids.Contains(p.PersonId)).GroupBy(p => p.PersonId);
foreach (var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(group.Key + ": " + group.Sum(p => p.Age));
}
```